# How to do implementation of search form functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to implement a search box in my angularJs application. As soon as user starts typing some name in the search box , some REST service should be called and it should fetch all the names which matches the name typed in the search text box. Note that there is no button , the result should come automatically as soon as user starts typing. The REST service is already there. I just need to invoke the REST service when the user starts typing and return the result as a list. For ex:- If I type James then all the user whose name starts with James should come as a list in the search box.

Comment: Post us what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Add following section in html code -

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in nameList|filter:searchText">
             <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the code for main.js file -

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.nameList = [{name:"ABC"}, {name:"DEF"},{name:"GHI"},
                      //Define list here
                      ];
}
```